# Recuperar valor do select via JS e jogar na variável PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Eu preciso pegar o valor escolhido do select e jogar numa *query*, como fazer?
Na prática (seguindo o exemplo) eu escolho no select um motorista e este select vai retornar abaixo todos os registros referentes à este motorista, talvez os campos possam ser data da viagem, veiculo, etc.. (é só um exemplo), tudo isso sem um botão de submit ou outro qualquer.

Eu tenho o seguinte select list:

```
<select name="regiao" onchange="run()" id="regiao">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Escolha a Região</option>
 <?php 
 //listar regioes
    $db->select_pdo("SELECT * FROM regiaos order by indOrdem ASC"); 
    foreach($db->result as $value){
      echo '<option value="'.$value['idRegiao'].'">'.$value['txtDescricao'].'</option>';
    } 
 ?>
</select>

E o Javascript:

<script>
   function run() {
    document.getElementById("rstregiao").value = document.getElementById("regiao").value;
   }
</script>

E o resultado (que imprime o html c o valor correto, porém eu precisaria do valor sem o html para rodar a variável na query): 

<?php 
  $regiaos = '<input type="text" id="rstregiao" placeholder="valor">';
    echo $regiaos; 
    //listar redecredenciadas 
    $db->select_pdo("SELECT * FROM redecredenciadas WHERE idRegiao = '$regiaos' order by txtNome ASC"); 
    foreach($db->result as $value){
      unset($credenciada);  
      $credenciada = $value['txtNome'];
        echo $credenciada; }
?>
```

----->

Agora eu tenho a seguinte situação:

O COMBO atualiza a página da query, o resultado retorna e é impresso, porém na impressão não estou conseguindo fazer que a formatação do loop fique coerente com a tabela, segue abaixo meus arquivos para quem puder ajudar, e claro, o @Thomas também que tem ajudado e muito! (obrigado mesmo)

--> JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("body").delegate("#regiao", "change", function(data){

                //Pegando o valor do select
                var valor = $(this).val();
                //Enviando o valor do meu select para ser processado e
                //retornar as informações que eu preciso
                $("#conteudo").load("regiaos.php?parametro="+ valor);

            });
        });
</script>
```

--> PAGINA DA QUERY

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");

$parametro = $_GET['parametro'];
$db->select_pdo("SELECT * FROM redecredenciadas WHERE idRegiao = '$parametro' ORDER BY idRegiao ASC");
    foreach($db->result as $value){
    echo '<tr>
            <td>- '.$value['txtNome'].'</td>';
    }
?>
```

--> PAGINA COM O RESULTADO IMPRESSO (com a formatação errada por conta da TAG que precisa ter o

Nome da Unidade Credenciada
            Ativo
            AOP
            POP
            APC
            HO
            PSI
            PSO
            H
            PS
            M
            PA
            HP
            AMB
            PS Inf

--> O RESULTADO NA TELA

Nome da Unidade Credenciada | Ativo |AOP|POP|APC|HO|PSI|PSO|H|PS|M|PA|HP|AMB|PS Inf
- unidade 01                |  chk  | ch|ch |ch |ch|ch |ch |c|ch|c|ch|ch|ch | chk
- unidade 02
- unidade 03
etc...   e os chechbox (chk) não estão dentro do loop as unidades estão em uma unica celula (eu disse que era ridículo)

Obrigado

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. E o que você fez até aqui? Procure detalhar melhor sua pergunta. Leia [ask] e faça um [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parceiro, vejo 2 soluções para isso:

1ª - Quando chamar a função run() no JavaScript, pegue o valor do seu select e utilize-o em um redirecionamento passando-o como parâmetro:

```
var valor = document.getElementById("regiao").value;    
window.location = "pagina.php?parametro=valor"
```

2ª - Particularmente, considero essa segunda solução a melhor:
Utilize o jQuery. Você pode usar os métodos $.get(), $.post(), $.ajax() ou ainda usar o método .load(). Assim você conseguirá fazer sua query sem usar refresh().

Segue abaixo um exemplo de codigo:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("body").delegate("#regiao", "change", function(data){

                //Pegando o valor do select
                var valor = $(this).val();
                //Enviando o valor do meu select para ser processado e
                //retornar as informações que eu preciso
                $("#conteudo").load("query.php?parametro="+ valor);

            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
<select name="regiao" id="regiao">
    <option value="1">Marcos da Silva</option>
    <option value="2">João da Silva</option>
    <option value="3">Roberto da Silva</option>
</select>

<div id="conteudo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**query.php**

```
<?php

$parametro = $_GET['parametro'];

//Aqui você pode fazer a sua query, e buscar os dados de um banco de dados

?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Idade</th>
            <th>Próxima Viagem</th>
            <th>Veículo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if ($parametro == 1): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Marcos da Silva</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>01/02/2015</td>
                <td>Fiorino</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($parametro == 2): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>João da Silva</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>21/02/2015</td>
                <td>Sprinter</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($parametro == 3): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Roberto da Silva</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>10/03/2015</td>
                <td>Doblo</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No arquivo query.php você faz a tua consulta e traz os dados e formata da forma como bem quiser.
Veja que cada vez que você altera o valor do select, ele chama a query.php e executa o que eu quero.

Espero ter ajudado =)

Comment: Thomas, obrigado pelo retorno, mas é que a linha $regiaos = '<input type="text" id="rstregiao" placeholder="valor">';
    echo $regiaos; , nesta echo da variável $regiaos vem o número correto dentro de um html (campo input) que eu não quero, como tirar este html e pegar só o numero? Não sei se fui claro, mas é justamente isso que preciso, pois este numero jogo na query na mesma página, valeu!

Comment: O problema é que PHP e JavaScript trabalham de forma diferente: PHP precisa ser enviado para o servidor interpretar, e o Javascript é executado no browser. Com isso, cada vez que você selecionar algum registro no SELECT, você é obrigado a submeter essa página. Ai você poderia usar a primeira solução, e trocar essa linha do $regiaos = '<input..., por $regiaos = $_GET['parametro']. A vantagem de usar o jQuery é que você não precisa submeter a página, cada vez que você escolhe um valor no SELECT, ele automaticamente executa sua query.

Comment: eu sei que cada um roda em uma "ponta", e achava que havia uma solução para isto, e depois de ler tua resposta fiquei achando mais ainda que é possível (rs), voce poderia repassar este código pra eu tentar rodar aqui, pois fiquei confuso com tanta parte (muito bem explicada) de exemplos, entende? tks?>  - prefiro usar Jquery (apesar de não manjar) e evitar mandar pra outra página (se isso for possível)

Comment: Editei minha resposta, teste esses 2 códigos e veja se era isso que você queria.

Comment: era exatamente isto que eu precisava. Já utilizava um script e uma pagina anexa para poder preencher uma sequencia de combos, mas achei que poderia ser em uma única página a solução desta questão. Valeu muito sua ajuda e espero que o código sirva à outros! Obrigado!

Comment: Acho que você até consegue fazer em uma página só, se no .load() você passar a mesma página que está usando, passando alguns parâmetros. Porém, acredito que não seja uma boa prática, já que o interessante é você separar funções. Que bom que consegui ajudar =) Vlw!

Comment: e demais colaboradores, agora preciso imprimir os resultados mas o problema esta sendo trabalhar com as <tr> e <td> pois referenciando a tag id="conteudo" não estou conseguindo formatar corretamente a quebra de linha, como postar aqui os códigos de forma correta para sua visualização? Obrigado

Comment: sugiro que você edite a sua pergunta, ou crie uma nova com os códigos que você está usando e o que você quer fazer! =)

Comment: eu fiz alterações no seu texto incluindo tudo mas não aparece....

Comment: sim, eu vi, tive que recusar devido as regras do site. Nas respostas, só devem conter RESPOSTAS. Dúvidas e outros problemas devem ser feitos via comentário ou com outra pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe, sou novo aqui, mas como eu pergunto de novo sem perder o vinculo daqui e sua colaboração? Aqui no comentário eu não consigo disponibilizar tantas linhas de código. Obrigado

Comment: Sem problemas, também estou aprendendo ainda. Edite a sua pergunta colocando no final o seu novo problema, e ai eu edito a minha resposta, ou acrescento uma nova resposta.

Comment: Já alterei na minha pergunta mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Eduardo, poste o código da página HTML onde está o seu combobox

Comment: Olá @Thomas e todos, desculpe a demora para ler a tua solicitação. vou postar abaixo:<select name="regiao" id="regiao">
               <option value="0" selected="selected">Escolha a Região</option>
             <?php 
     //listar regioes
     $db->select_pdo("SELECT * FROM regiaos order by indOrdem ASC");
     foreach($db->result as $value){
    ?>
               <strong>
    <?php
                echo '<option value="'.$value['idRegiao'].'">'.$value['txtDescricao'].'</option>';} ?>
                </strong>
             </select>, este select funciona OK, resultado OK, o lance é que o HTML

Comment: da página fica em branco, mas o resultado na página fica visível. então o problema estaria em como utilizar os valores dos checkboxes selecionados deste resultado?

Comment: Olá de novo, parei com este código pois o que acontece: na pagina html todos os combos são preenchidos neste vai e vem, porém o resultado que retorna do JS não pode ser mais utilizado, ele é impresso na página mas não faz parte do código, tanto que visualizando o código da página você não vê este conteúdo, apenas as TAGs onde ele deve aparecer. É o cenário esperado quando trabalhamos com JS e PHP. Creio que não há mais saída para isto, há? Obrigado